# How to manually increase Brightness in Pillow np.ndarray

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, python-imaging-library

Im trying to make an Image Editor in Python using tkinter. I've developped functions to manipulate images, increasing brightness, contrast and so on. I've been getting really wierd results when converting the array back to a Pillow Image using Image.fromarray()

I know there are built in methods to increase brightness, but i'd like to expand this to more complex things. So converting Image to array and the other way arround is so important.

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

class Imagem:
    def __init__(self, path_imagem):
        self.image = Image.open(path_imagem)

    def brightness(self, factor):
        array_imagem = np.array(self.imagem)
        array_imagem = array_imagem + factor
        self.image = Image.fromarray(array_imagem, mode='RGB')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    img = Imagem('./assets/panda.png')
    img.brightness(30)
    img.image.show()
```

This is the original Image and the image I'm getting back
[original](https://i.stack.imgur.com/swLDO.jpg)
[modified](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hLXSC.jpg)

(These are prints from the images, I couldn't upload the original images due to size constraints)

shouldn't I be adding 30 (in this case) to all rgb pixel values?

Answer:

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

class Imagem:
    def __init__(self, path_imagem):
        self.image = Image.open(path_imagem)

    def brightness(self, factor):
        array_imagem = np.array(self.imagem)
        array_imagem = array_imagem.astype(np.uint16)
        array_imagem = array_imagem + factor
        array_imagem = np.clip(array_imagem, a_min=0, a_max=255)
        self.image = Image.fromarray(array_imagem.astype(np.uint8), mode='RGB')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    img = Imagem('./assets/panda.png')
    img.brightness(30)
    img.image.show()
```

Thank you for the help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By adding 30, you have overflowed the 0..255 range that can be stored in a `uint8`. You can see that the brightest areas have burnt out.

You need to promote your data to a larger type, e.g. `uint16`, and then call `np.clip()` to clamp the values into the range 0..255 and convert back to `uint8` to prevent it.

Also, adding 30 to all RGB channels is not ideal. You will normally get a better result by changing to **Lab** mode or **HSL** and just increasing the `L` channel, else you'll tend to get colour distortions.

Comment: I've tried that as well. I just forgot to include it here. But the output is just the same using array_imagem = (array_imagem, a_min=0, a_max=255, dtype=uint8)

Comment: I'm trying it this way because I've already had success increasing a scalar (like 30) to all channels using imread from matplotlib for example. But I had to migrate to Pillow for tkinter better interactions and I can't see why it doesnt work the same way.

Comment: If you've already added to the smaller uint8 type, it will have already overflowed. You need to promote to uint16 first, then add, then clip. Otherwise it is too late you can't clip it because adding 30 to 250 is already going to give you a small positive answer that doesn't respond to clipping.

Comment: Am I not doing it correctly in Edit 1? First making the array uint16, adding and clipping with uint8? I'm kinda new to dtype manipulation using numpy

Comment: Try `a = np.full((1,1), 250, np.uint8)` to make single pixel of 250. Then add 30 with `a += 30` and now `print(a)`. It is 24.

Comment: Thats exactly it! I've changed the dtype in a separate line, and not inside the clip function. Worked like a charm. Thank you brotha